# Why didn't the Avengers use the Mind stone to change the minds of the Black Order or Thanos?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

We know from *The Avengers* that Loki uses his Scepter (which houses the Mind Stone) to control the free will of Clint Barton & Erik Selvig.

Vision had the Mind stone with him all the time. Why didn't he use it to alter the minds of Black Order, or Thanos when Thanos held him during the end of *Avengers: Infinity War*?

Did Vision or any other Avenger not know how to use it?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I can understand the downvotes, but I don't see how this is opinion-based. It's clearly established in the MCU that Vision doesn't understand how the Time Stone works and doesn't know how to use its powers.

Comment: Vision has repeatedly said he doesn't understand the capabilities of the stone.  I'm sure he does this in both Captain America Civil War and Infinity War.

Comment: We've also never been given any evidence that Vision has any powers other than the beam of energy he can emit from it, his strength and flying and being able to phase so he can pass through matter.  He's never shown any ability to control minds.  I will add all this as an answer if its re-opened.  I hesitate to re-open it just for me to add an answer.

Comment: It was more than two years post civil war. During civil war vision might have been unfamiliar with the stone. But he must of records of sceptor being able to control people minds. So vision must of learnt it's abilities. If cyborg of DC could learn unknown stuff every why day why can't vision do the same

Comment: He repeats in Infinity War the point that he doesn't understand the stone. Also you can't translate the world of DC into Marvel or visa-versa.

Comment: @iandotkelly that sounds like a perfect answer to this question. No opinion involved here.

Comment: https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/89127/5315 relevant discussion in this answer & comments

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Because they can't.

The Vision does not have complete control over the Mind Stone (at best he uses it as a "force beam")...he says as much to Wanda in *Captain America: Civil War*.

Certainly there is *no* indication he can control minds with it.

> **Vision**: Do you know, I don't know what this is? Not really. I know it's not of this world...that it powered Loki's staff, gave you your abilities, but... **its true nature is a mystery.** And yet, it is part of me.
>
> **Wanda**: Are you afraid of it?
>
> **Vision**: I wish to understand it. The more I do, the less it controls me. One day... who knows?

Comment: While this is not this answer's fault, I personally think this is a pretty big hole in the MCU. At no point did Stark want to investigate the Mind Stone more completely than to leave it and Vision to do what they wanted to do? It seems odd that in Endgame, Stark would have already taken the time to create an Infinity Gauntlet but not have understood the individual stones well enough to use them not-in-unison.